# When the sum of the first $n$ consecutive even ($2k \gt 0$) powers is a prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

When $n=2$, we know 4 Fermat primes (among the 5 which are known) satisfying this condition:

$$ 1^2+2^2 =5$$
$$ 1^4+2^4 =17$$
$$ 1^8+2^8 = 257$$
$$ 1^{16}+2^{16} = 65537.$$

One may wonder for what other values of $(n,k)$, it holds that $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2k}$ is a prime number.

Apparently, when $n=5$ and $2k= 1440$,
\begin{align*} \sum_{i=1}^5 i^{1440}&=32870494973745590489672618520147226309471918340144695384282781773232645934767374502515598230671247791137527930976112524088008871699095171820372590939626862942685233205917502232958206871013324680536478277482222732171441694215728644181003593159822253865262588786239180084214018426223815623365507773026858373360823443708140883611306592330902932994635589466928339291445175747183614303780853567119243706761062506654051875550472877972022914140455264123266196392819668763698772234814545138902251784786312525104750087996929330185562414784278046396853711290578794116661635417485831969776614488207040722193777994839584756032261597855392326049625939136446894123910001325456787924317732389996265611844035119303216257160839794599676231991399494717047707966247305837634999211674025286390932779274786302608986436901299610556101262201055350271221229232970792516169435984584890424504786508517368097919942459145192988140070892281836785524154439529178872700448867894407573012070924416033111999815571623367458593539025033893379 \end{align*}
is a $1007$ digits prime number.

Anyone knows another one? (with $n \gt 2$ and $k\gt0$)

I am also interested in any necessary conditions on $n$ and $k$ for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2k}$ to be prime. Clearly neither $n$ nor $n+1$ can be a multiple of $4$.

More generally, if $q$ is an odd prime number such that $q-1$ divides $2k$, $n$ cannot be $ 0\bmod {q^2} $ otherwise   $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2k}\equiv \sum_{i\le n ,\mathrm {gcd}(i,q)=1} 1 = n-\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}}\rfloor \equiv 0 \pmod q $$ and cannot be a prime number. Then $n$ cannot be a multiple of $9$.

Also if $q$ is an odd prime number such that $q-1$ divides $2k$, $n+1$ cannot be $0  \bmod {q^2} $ either, otherwise   $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{2k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^{2k}-(n+1)^{2k}\equiv \sum_{i\le n+1 ,\mathrm {gcd}(i,q)=1} 1 = n+1-\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}}\rfloor \equiv 0 \pmod q $$ and cannot be a prime number. Then $n+1$ cannot be a multiple of $9$ either.

And also if $q$ is an odd prime number such that $q-1$ divides $2k$, $2n+1$ cannot be $0 \bmod {q^2} $ either, otherwise
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} i^{2k}-\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n+1} i^{2k}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} i^{2k}-\sum_{i=0}^{n} (2n+1-i)^{2k}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k} \equiv \sum_{\underset{i\le 2n+1 }{\mathrm {gcd}(i,q)=1}} 1- \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k}\equiv 2n+1-\lfloor {\frac{2n+1}{q}}\rfloor - n +\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}}\rfloor \equiv - n +\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}}\rfloor\pmod q.$$
But neither $n$ nor $n+1$ is multiple of $q$, otherwise both would be (since $q$ divides $2n+1$) which is impossible since $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime. Then $\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}}\rfloor=\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}}\rfloor$, then
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k} \equiv  - n +\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}} \rfloor\equiv 2n+1-n+\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}} \rfloor\equiv n+1+\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}} \rfloor\pmod q,$$ then
$$2\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k} \equiv  1 +\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}} \rfloor+\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}} \rfloor\pmod q.$$
But
$$\frac{2n+1}{q}-1=\lfloor {\frac{2n+1}{q}} \rfloor-1 \le \lfloor {\frac{n}{q}} \rfloor+\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}} \rfloor \le \lfloor {\frac{2n+1}{q}} \rfloor= \frac{2n+1}{q} $$

and $$\lfloor {\frac{n}{q}} \rfloor+\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}}\rfloor \neq \frac{2n+1}{q} $$ then

$$\frac{2n+1}{q}-1= \lfloor {\frac{n}{q}} \rfloor+\lfloor {\frac{n+1}{q}} \rfloor $$

$$2\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k} \equiv  \frac{2n+1}{q}\equiv 0 \pmod q$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^{2k} \equiv 0 \pmod q$$
and cannot be a prime number.

Then $2n+1$ cannot be a multiple of $9$ either.

So we have shown that $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ cannot be divisible by $4$ nor by $9$ and  I can show that a more general necessary condition is that $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is squarefree. The proof is hereafter in the Appendix.

I also wonder whether another necessary condition is that the prime divisors of $2k$ are smaller than or equal to those of $n$. But we only have $1440=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot 5$ and the Fermat primes to support this.

**Appendix**

Let $\mathrm{rad}(n)$ be the product of the distinct prime factors of $n$.
The purpose of this appendix is to show that when $k\ge1$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n j^{2k} \equiv 0 \bmod {\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{\mathrm{rad} \big(n(n+1)(2n+1)\big)}}$$ whence if $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is not squarefree, then $\sum_{i=1}^n j^{2k}$ is composite.

We first observe that it suffices to show that $S_{2k}(n):=\sum_{j=1}^nj^{2k}$ is divisible by $\frac{n}{\mathrm{rad}(n)}$. Indeed $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime and $S_{2k}(n)= S_{2k}(n+1)-(n+1)^{2k}$ is then also divisible by $\frac{n+1}{\mathrm{rad}(n+1)}$ , since $(n+1)^{2k}$ is divisible by $(n+1)^{2}$, hence by $\frac{n+1)}{\mathrm{rad}(n+1)}$ . Also $n$ and $2n+1$ are coprime and $S_{2k}(n)= S_{2k}(2n+1)-\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n+1}i^{2k}=S_{2k}(2n+1)-\sum_{i=0}^{n}(2n+1-i)^{2k}$, then
$$S_{2k}(n)\equiv -\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2k}= -S_{2k}(n)\bmod {\frac{2n+1}{\mathrm{rad}(2n+1)}} $$
then $$2S_{2k}(n)\equiv 0\bmod {\frac{2n+1}{\mathrm{rad}(2n+1)}} $$
then $$S_{2k}(n)\equiv 0\bmod {\frac{2n+1}{\mathrm{rad}(2n+1)}} $$

Let $q$ be a prime divisor of $n$. By @reuns remark in the comment,  $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}\equiv \frac{n}{q}\sum_{j=1}^{q-1}j^{2k} \bmod q$ and this clearly shows that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^{2k}\equiv 0 \bmod q$ when $q^2$ divides $n$. $\square$

Comment: According to Mathematica, $(n,k) = (5,720)$ is the only solution for $3\le n\le 100$, $1\le k \le 2000$.

Comment: @reuns  I did. This remark will make my appendix much more simple. I will adapt it accordingly, Thanks.

Comment: Also did you try looking at the prime factors of the non-prime $S_{2k}(n)$ (those coprime with $n(n+1)(2n+1)$) it might give some clues.

Comment: @reuns I did something like that: I looked numerically for the $n\ge 2$ for which, I could find $k$ with $\mathrm {gcd}\big(S_{2k}(n),(2n+1)!\big)=1$. I found $n =2, 5, 10, 21, 29, 30, 33, 34, 41, 46, 61, 66, 69, 77, 78, 82, 86, 101, 105, 109, 110, 129, 133, 142, 145, 185, 194,\cdot\cdot$. Of course there might be gaps in this list since I have to put a limit on $k$ for the search.

Comment: @reuns Now the list of $n$ such that $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ is square free is $n=  2, 5, 6, 10, 14, 21, 29, 30, 33, 34, 38, 41, 42, 46, 57, 61, 65, 
66, 69, 70, 77, 78, 82, 86, 93, 101, 102, 105, 106, 109, 110, 113,
114, 118, 129, 133, 138, 141, 142, 145, 154, 158, 165, 173, 177, 178, 
182, 185, 186, 190, 194,\cdot\cdot$)

Comment: @reuns interestingly, $6$ is in the second list, but I believe that it is not in the first one, since I think it can be shown that $S_{2k}(6)$ is multiple of $13$ or of $5$. Also $14$ is in the second list but I believe it cannot belong to the first one as I think I can show that $S_{2k}(14)$ is multiple of $29$ or of $7$ or of $13$.

Comment: I am now looking if I can show that for $n=38$ which is not in my first list, I can find a set of prime numbers $\le 2n+1=77$ in which whatever $k$ there is at least one prime divisor of $S_{2k}(38)$.  But I don't really understand what is going on here..